# Django RestFramework How to let field allow post but now allow put

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer:

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x_axis = serializers.FloatField()
    y_axis = serializers.FloatField()
    map_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='area_map_id')
```

And I have a `ListCreateAPIView` and  a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` use it
But I want the field `map_id` can allow POST method, not allow PUT method

I mean if POST the data below is OK

```
{
"x_axis":1,
"y_axis":2,
"map_id":1  
}
```

if PUT the data below is still OK

```
{
"x_axis":1,
"y_axis":2,
"map_id":1  
}
```

But the `map_id` will not have influence the database
if the database saved with the map_id=2, it will still 2 ,it will not be edit to 1

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another serializer `AreaPutSerializer` which will inherit from `AreaSerializer` for handling `PUT` requests.

In `AreaPutSerializer`, we will set `map_id` field as `read_only` using `extra_kwargs` option. Doing this will ensure that in `PUT` requests, `map_id` field will be included in the API output but not be used in write operations.

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x_axis = serializers.FloatField()
    y_axis = serializers.FloatField()
    map_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='area_map_id')

class AreaPutSerializer(AreaSerializer):

    class Meta(AreaSerializer.Meta):
        extra_kwargs = {'map_id': {'read_only':True}}
```

In your view, then you can add a `get_serializer_class` method which will return the serializer class to be used depending on the request method.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'PUT':
        return AreaPutSerializer
    return AreaSerializer
```